# How to make the text center vertical in a line in TextView of Android

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, line, center

I have a **multi-line** edit text with a **100dp lineSpacingExtra**.

Now the text is shown at the top of a line. And the cursor's height is same as line height , it's much taller than the text's height.

How can I make the text shown in the center of the line?
Or if I can adjust the padding top or padding bottom of the text in a line.

Note:
What I mean is NOT using android:gravity="center_vertical" to make the text center vertical in the TextView.
I want to show the text center vertically in the line.

The xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textShortMessage"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="100dp"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:minLines="10"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="Text ABCDE\n Line2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated.
THX!

Comment: Show your xml and snapshot here.

Comment: There is no way to do it with just EditText, you should create a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout to wrap around the EditText, set the LinearLayout or RelativeLayout gravity to Gravity.Center, set EditText height to Wrap_Content, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach my result here:
There's no way to do this in an application.
Because the TextView draws the text at the top of a line in framework.
If u want the visual effect that the text shown center vertically in a line, the framework code must be modified.
The file location is:
frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/StaticLayout.java

The change:

```
-        lines[off + DESCENT] = below + extra;
+        lines[off + DESCENT] = below + extra/2;//Show the text center vertically in the line.
```

Please correct me if something is wrong or there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Edited Answer:

Output is:

[image]

Code (from my own xml tag, so change your id):

```
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_feedback"
                android:layout_width="401dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_six"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textfield_activated_holo_dark"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:hint="Em   "
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ed_feedback_know"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/textfield_empty_holo_dark"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="Text ABCDE\n Line2"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what I need is to show the text in the center of its line, while not show the text in the center of the TextView.

Comment: Hey WJ S, thanks for pointing out the exact problem, i have edited my answer. Hope, it will help you

Comment: Sorry, I've missed emphasizing that the edit text is multi-line, and the lineSpacingExtra is 100dp. If you do this, it's easy to find that the text is shown at the top side of the line. And I wanna put the text at the center of the line with a big lineSpacingExtras. Anyway, thanks for your warm help. :)